# Getting data from ref Node (JavaScript web scraping)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using Cheerio to scrape a couple websites to use for a project. This code gets data from a website and pushes it into a couple different arrays.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to isolate the price information. Here's my NodeJS code:

```
// Gets all available keyboards from 
mykeyboard.eu (first page only) //
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
const MyKeyboardEU ='https://mykeyboard.eu/catalogue/category/mechanical-keyboards_3/?selected_facets=num_in_stock_exact%3A%5B1+TO+%2A%5D';
const MKEUResults = [];
const MKEUThumbs = [];
const MKEUPrice = [];

// Gets in-stock results from mykeyboard.eu //
Axios.get(MyKeyboardEU)
    .then((response) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        let keyboards = $('.thumbnail')
        let price = $('.price_color').children;

        // Pushes keyboard names + thumbnail links to respective arrays //
        for (var i = 0; i < keyboards.length; i++) {
            MKEUResults.push(keyboards[i].attribs.alt);
            MKEUThumbs.push(keyboards[i].attribs.src);
            console.log(price[i]);
        }

        // Maps array into single object for consuption on frontend //
        let arr = MKEUResults.map((res, idx) => {
            return {'name': res, "img": MKEUThumbs[idx]}
        });

        res.send(arr);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.send(err));
});
```

Here is what the console.log(price[i]) outputs:

```
 <ref *1> [
keeb-finder-server-1  |   Node {
keeb-finder-server-1  |     type: 'text',
keeb-finder-server-1  |     data: '€179.00',
keeb-finder-server-1  |     parent: Node {
keeb-finder-server-1  |       type: 'tag',
keeb-finder-server-1  |       name: 'p',
keeb-finder-server-1  |       namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
keeb-finder-server-1  |       attribs: [Object: null prototype],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       children: [Circular *1],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       parent: [Node],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       prev: [Node],
keeb-finder-server-1  |       next: [Node]
keeb-finder-server-1  |     },
keeb-finder-server-1  |     prev: null,
keeb-finder-server-1  |     next: null
keeb-finder-server-1  |   }
keeb-finder-server-1  | ]
```

For the record, it outputs several of these messages pertaining to different items on their website. I just want to get the **data** component of all these responses.

I'm sure it's something fairly simple that I missed when reading the docs, but I can't seem to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the prices by doing:

```js
var prices = $('.price_color').map(function() {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
console.log('prices', prices);
```

Additionally, you can simplify your code for the `alt` and `src` thumbnails by doing:

```
var thumbnails = $('.thumbnail').map(function() {
  return {'alt':$(this).attr('alt'), 'src':$(this).attr('src')};
}).toArray();
console.log('thumbnails', thumbnails);
```

Finally, if you'd like to get the `src`, `alt`, and `price` in one loop, then you can do the below. It really simplifies the code and makes it easier to understand.

```js
var products = $('.product_pod').map(function() {
  let image = $(this).find('.thumbnail');
  let price = $(this).find('.price_color').text().trim();
  return {'src':image.attr('src'), 'alt':image.attr('alt'), 'price':price};
}).toArray();
console.log('products', products);
```